# Rebol 2 process on Linux halts on SIGTERM after a "day of heavy load"

Tags: linux, rebol, rebol2, cheyenne

I am using Cheyenne for a relatively high-load web application. It works great and fast. But I have a problem that started appearing after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04, or I started noticing it then because the load increased.

After few days of working, when a Rebol worker process should exit, the process starts to consume 100% CPU and "does nothing". I looked at process  with **strace** and when it's in 100 CPU it doesn't call the OS in any way. I looked at the Cheyenne worker code (if there is any fault there) and the code executes OK to the Rebol command **exit**. This command makes it loop forever. It's the same if I try to kill the process with **sigterm**.

I can then kill it with **sigkill**. The process only gets into this state after few days of heavy load, and I haven't been able to replicate it in non-production environment or on local computer.

My naive thinking is that it loops forever while trying to clear it's memory before exiting, or maybe the open files / sockets. I looked the processes before/after with **lsof** (and similar), but since the event isn't easily reproducible haven't figured anything out yes.

My question is: has anyone seen Rebol2 go into eternal 100% loop on exit  and under which circumstances? Does anyone have any idea about solving this?

Comment: **This is not going to be a useful comment I'm afraid but here goes.**   I also use Cheyenne on Ubuntu 14.04 (to be precise: 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64) and I've never seen this problem. Ditto on Ubuntu 16.04 & Mac OSX 10.9.  It should be noted that these have never been put under heavy load but there are long running (some cases 6-9 months without restart).

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this on our production cheyenne servers, with 100% cpu not responding, probably after serving a very long file (lot of datas in the response)... Never managed to find time to diagnostic more this issue, ending writing a monitor in go that kills 100% cpu process for a too long time.

https://github.com/Softinnov/bearded-monitor

You can use it in a docker container

https://hub.docker.com/r/softinnov/bearded-monitor/

Hope it helps.